# RoleMapping.USER or RoleMapping.ROLE & ACL

Tags: node.js, acl, loopbackjs

I'm using the [loopback framework](http://loopback.io/).

It is not very clear to me when to use RoleMapping with static roles and ACL, also after reading the  documentation [here](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Defining+and+using+roles#Definingandusingroles-Staticroles) and [here](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Controlling+data+access).

I have a boot script where I insert some major static roles in my application (admin, approver, validator, etc) and I use those roles in ACL.

Seems to me that when I declare the user role I have to use `RoleMapping.USER`:

```
const approver = yield app.models.User.create({
  email: 'approver@lorem.com',
  password: 'secret-apprpver-123',
  status: 'active',
  emailVerified: true
});

const roleApprover = yield app.models.Role.findOne({
  where: {name: 'approver'}
});

yield app.models.RoleMapping.create({
  principalId: approver.id,
  principalType: app.models.RoleMapping.USER,
  roleId: roleApprover.id
});
```

While in the ACL I have to use `RoleMapping.ROLE`:

```
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",

  "accessType": "EXECUTE",
  "principalId": "approver",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "setApprove"
}
```

But it is not very clear, with a lot of headache every time I have to debug it, some dark magic and praying each time I have to manage new roles or new ACL.

Is there someone that can explain me how to do it?

Comment: In the first code block you are adding a user to the role, in the second block (the ACL config) you are allowing the role to take an action on a model. The two actions work in unison to provide authorization and authentication respectively. What part do you not understand exactly?

Comment: at a first look I would use the same `principalType` for both.. your explanations seems good but can you expand it a little bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(just putting this into an answer...)

In the first code block you are creating a user and a role, then adding that user to the role. In the second block (the ACL model config) you are allowing that role (and anyone in it) to take an action on a model (specifically in this case executing the `setApprove()` method). The two actions work in unison to provide authorization and authentication respectively.

To address the follow up comment, the `principalType` in the model config ACL is `"ROLE"` because you want anyone in that role to be able to take that action. If you instead made the `principalType` `"USER"` then you would have to change the `principalId` to the new User ID and you would be only authorizing that one user (regardless of who is in the role) to take that action.